# Torrent upload doesn't work

Tags: upload, bittorrent

I'm trying to create a torrent to share a large number of pictures with my family, but I can't get the upload to work.
As a proof of concept I'm first trying to seed and leech the file to myself. Here's what I tried:

In ~/torrent_upload:

```
ctorrent -t -u "udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce" -s example.torrent ./data.zip
cp ./example.torrent ../torrent_download/example.torrent
ctorrent ./example.torrent
```

In ~/torrent_download:

```
ctorrent ./example.torrent
```

Here are the outputs:

For torrent_upload:

```
META INFO
Announce: udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce
Created On: Thu Jan 12 19:40:46 2017
Piece length: 262144
Created with: Enhanced-CTorrent/dnh3.3.2

FILES INFO
<1> ./2016_11_05.zip [186422111]
Total: 177 MB
warn, couldn't set bit field refer file "example.torrent.bf":  No such file or directory
This is normal if you are seeding.
Listening on 0.0.0.0:2706
Press 'h' or '?' for help (display/control client options).
- 0/0/1 [1/712/1] 0MB,0MB | 0,0K/s | 0,0K E:0,0 Connecting                      
Checking completed.

FILES INFO
<1> ./2016_11_05.zip [186422111] 712/712 (100%)
Total: 177 MB
Seed for others 72 hours

\ 0/0/1 [712/712/712] 0MB,0MB | 0,0K/s | 0,0K E:0,0  Connecting
```

with final line staying at `Connecting`

For torrent_download:

```
META INFO
Announce: udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce
Created On: Thu Jan 12 19:40:46 2017
Piece length: 262144
Created with: Enhanced-CTorrent/dnh3.3.2

FILES INFO
<1> ./2016_11_05.zip [186422111]
Total: 177 MB
Creating file "./2016_11_05.zip"
Listening on 0.0.0.0:2705
Press 'h' or '?' for help (display/control client options).
/ 0/0/1 [0/712/0] 0MB,0MB | 0,0K/s | 0,0K E:0,0 Connecting
```

again with final line staying at `Connecting`. Running ctorrents in verbal mode doesn't really add any useful info. I just see repeating lines similar to:

```
1484220255 Cache: 0K/16M  Hits: 0  Miss: 0  0%  Pre: 0/0
/ 0/0/1 [712/712/712] 0MB,0MB | 0,0K/s | 0,0K E:0,0 Connecting                  
1484220256 Cache: 0K/16M  Hits: 0  Miss: 0  0%  Pre: 0/0
- 0/0/1 [712/712/712] 0MB,0MB | 0,0K/s | 0,0K E:0,0 Connecting
```

on both processes.

Any idea what am I missing? Reading around some people say it's a port issue and I need to open the port in router to allow upload, although not everyone seems to agree with that. I tred opening port 2706 that uploading ctorrent was listening on, but that didn't change anything.

Others are blaming tracker sites. I don't know how to verify if a tracker I use works or not, but I tried several, all with the same result.

I thought maybe tracker sites need some time to start wiring peers, but I left both upload and download processes overnight and it didn't work.

I already set my IP address to static - and at any rate I think it shouldn't matter considering I'm doing essentially local to local connection now.

I tried downloading popular torrents, like Ubuntu images, to make sure download part isn't broken and it works like a charm.

---

EDIT in response to Seth's questions:

I tried seeding latest Ubuntu ISO on two different machines. Running in normal mode it looked like nothing was uploaded, but here are excerpts of verbose mode:

```
1484232174 Connected to tracker
1484232174 Reported to tracker:  0 uploaded, 0 downloaded
1484232175 Disconnected from tracker
1484232175 new peers=50; next check in 1800 sec
1484232175 Connecting to 178.62.36.240:51413 (peer 0x7ff38a701b50)
1484232175 Connecting to 84.215.30.5:51413 (peer 0x7ff38a702140)
...
1484232175 peer 0x7ff38a502230 gave 0x00000000001000 as reserved bytes
1484232175 Peer 0x7ff38a502230 ID: -qB3370-70bW.N2QYtAi
...
1484232175 0x7ff38a5015d0: Connection reset by peer
1484232175 close: bad handshake
1484232175 0x7ff38a5015d0 close
...
1484232237 peer 0x7ff38d000bf0 gave 0x00000000001000 as reserved bytes
1484232237 Peer 0x7ff38d000bf0 ID: -TR2840-144jjvhhi98x
1484232237 0x7ff38a702ab0 bitfield has 99%
1484232237 0x7ff38a702ab0 seed<->seed detected
...
1484232175 Unknown message type 20 from peer 0x7ff38d200000
1484232175 0x7ff38d200000 is a seed (bitfield is full)
1484232175 0x7ff38d200000 seed<->seed detected
1484232175 close: receive
...
- 0/22/2903 [3040/3040/3040] 0MB,0MB | 0,0K/s | 0,0K E:0,3                      
1484232238 Cache: 0K/16M  Hits: 0  Miss: 0  0%  Pre: 0/0
```

It looks to me like some communication with peers is going on, though without any upload. Can't tell if that's because of some errors (e.g bad handsake, unknown message type 20, etc messages) or simply because Ubuntu is such a popular torrent that no peer needed anything from me.

I also tried seeding my torrent on one machine and downloading on another and see that both of them report repeated:

```
| 0/0/1 [712/712/712] 0MB,0MB | 0,0K/s | 0,0K E:0,0 Connecting                  
warn, connect to tracker failed:  Operation timed out
```

so it looks like a tracker problem after all. But I have that message with a bunch on different trackers I tried, so maybe it is something on my side that prevents communication with trackers, e.g. in how I created the torrent.

Comment: Did you compare the output with a working torrent and yours? Did you try to seed one of those torrents afterwards? Did you try it with two different devices?

Comment: @Seth - good questions, please see the updated info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was in fact problem with the tracker. After trying a fifth or sixth one I finally got uploading to work. Feel quite silly that was the reason, but thanks to Seth who got me digging into the problem hard enough to figure that out.

Comment: Don't forget that you can mark your own answer as the solution. Nice that you figured it out. Depending on the tracker configuration that tracker might just be excluding yourself (by chance) from the list of possible peers for that torrent.

Comment: @Seth Since I'm new on Superuser it won't let me mark my own reply as an answer until two full days have passed. I will then.